# Recursive Haskell function but only does part of it once

Tags: function, haskell, recursion

I've got a function that needs to work out the minimum change required to break down a certain amount of money.

A user would enter a value of money and the possible denominations, and it would output how many of each denomination would be needed to make up the money eg.

```
> coinChange 34 [1, 5, 10, 25, 50, 100] 
[4,1,0,1,0,0]
```

Here is what I have so far:

```
coinChange :: Integer -> [Integer] -> [Integer]
coinChange _ [] = []
coinChange 0 xs = []
coinChange v xs = do
                dropWhile (>v) (reverse xs)

createNewList :: Integer -> [Integer]
createNewList 0 = []
createNewList x = 0 : createNewList (x - 1)
```

I have a separate function called `createNewList` which I want to call to set up a new list of 0s at the beginning.

However, because I plan on making `coinChange` a recursive function when working out how much money is left, if I just call `makeNewList` in `coinChange`, at the moment it would reset the list because it would be called every recursion.

So my question is, is there a way to make a function call another function only once, before proceeding with the recursion.

Hope I've made it clear, thanks

Comment: Just make a recursive helper function then call that helper function from your actual function.

Comment: Expression `createNewList n` seems to be equivalent to the simpler  `replicate n 0`.

Comment: I don't see the need for creating a list of 0s. You'll be passing `tail xs` to the recursive call, and prepending something to its return value. E.g., `coinChange v (x:xs)= a : coinChange (v - b) xs`; you'll need to figure out what `a` and `b` should be.

Answer (score 0):

In general you are allowed to create local helper functions in Haskell. Maybe this example will inspire you:

```hs
prepareData x = if x < 0 then -x else x

mainFunction n =
  let recursiveLocalFunction x =
        if x < 2 then 1 else x * recursiveLocalFunction (x - 1)
  in recursiveLocalFunction (prepareData n)
```